# How to set ajax return value to a modal form?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, bootstrap-modal

I have a button, and when clicked, it then opens a modal form as well as sends an ajax request to a php page. I send an id from a table and in the php page that uses this id, and then I fetch a row with array from SQL Server 2008 database table and return it. How can I receive this value in ajax and use the value of a modal popup form?

Comment: Post the code, we need to see your button, your form, your ajax, your php, and your array.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use `echo json_encode($resultFromDataBase);` and read the result in your js.

Something like this:

```
<script> 
   $.post('someUrl',$('myForm').serialize(), function(data){
   //Here you can use result from dataBase and set to your form.
       $('someFieldOnModal').html(data.someField);
   },'json') 
</script>
```